Git subtree/ + inter-related gitignore
I want to setup a git project with a nested repo. so far my attempts with gitignores or git subtree dont catch all I need.
A) main repo

B) nested repo (core theme)
The nested repo contains a folder called 'local' that should be ignored by B-nested repo, but should not be ignored by in the main repo

In detail:
main repo : Should ignore ALL files except:

./backups
./content/themes/my-theme/local

the nested repo will be cloned at: ./content/themes/my-theme this should ignore its own child 'local/'
I have tried
main gitignore:
`# Ignore everything
/*
Do not ignore these directories
!/backups/
!/backups/*
!/content/themes/wp-theme-magstrap/local/
!/content/themes/wp-theme-magstrap/local/**
and the nested repo gitignore contains /local/*
